# which tag executed at first?<tiles:insert or <tiles:put

Tags: jakarta-ee, struts, struts-validation

in the above codings which one executed at first

Answer (score 1):

Since `tiles:put` works under `tiles:insert`, it is logical that `tiles:put` executes first and then `tiles:insert`. You will find more detail on this on Apache struts URL.